# Looking for VBA Method to Display a Word Mailmerge Formula on screen or Output to Excel/Other Word Document

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a word document with mailmerge fields and formula (mostly if statements).

The cells they are embedded in are so small that I cannot view either the field or the formula without copying and pasting the formula into Notepad.

Is there a way via VBA to:

1. Display the Mailmerge Field/Formula (via a msgbox or other) when I have highlighted the field?
2. Loop through all Mailmerge fields/formulae and output them to either another word doc or excel spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of your mailmerge main document, then run the following macro against the copy:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  Do While .Tables.Count > 0
    .Tables(1).ConvertToText vbTab
  Loop
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "[^32-^255]"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  .Style = wdStyleNormal
  .Font.Reset
  .Fields.Update
End With
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You should end up with a document containing just the fields (displayed), some images, tabs & paragraph/line breaks.

Comment: Thanks much for this out of the box solution.  Someone show develop a standalone editor/validator for Mailmerge Formula.  I would buy since working with MM formula is painful